# Uploading from Android to Amazon S3

Tags: android

I'm attempting to upload a .txt file from an android app into an Amazon S3 bucket.

As per the following [tutorial](http://wwwilpower.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/android-file-upload-to-amazon-s3-with.html) below is my code:

```
      // 
  public class PutOrderFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Long, Integer> {

    public MainActivity parentActivity;

    public PutOrderFilesTask(MainActivity receivedParentActivity) {
        this.parentActivity = receivedParentActivity;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        Map params = new HashMap();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse((parentActivity.getFilesDir()).toString());

        params.put("AWSAccessKeyId", "myAWSAccessKeyId");
        params.put("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        params.put("policy", "some-policy-defined-by-yourself");
        params.put("Filename", getManfcAndModelNumb() + ".txt");
        params.put("key", getManfcAndModelNumb() + ".txt");
        params.put("acl", "private");
        params.put("signature", "myApp");
        params.put("success_action_status", "201");

        Log.e("-o-o--o-o--o-o--o-o--o-o--o-o--o-o--o-o-", "-o-o--o-o--o-o--o-o--o-o--o-o--o-o--o-o--o-o--o-o--o-o--o-o--o-o--o-o--o-o--o-o--o-o");

        Log.e(TAG + " - doInBackground(String... arg0)", "Params have been set up");

        try {
            HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();

            Log.e(TAG + " - doInBackground(String... arg0)", "httpRequest object has been created.");

            httpRequest.postSocket("uri", 
                                    params, 
                                    parentActivity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), 
                                    this, 
                                    10, 
                                    70, 
                                    getManfcAndModelNumb() + ".txt", 
                                    getManfcAndModelNumb() + ".txt");

            Log.e(TAG + " - doInBackground(String... arg0)", "httpRequest.postSocket() has been called.");

                /*HttpRequest.postSocket("your-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com", params,
         context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)
         fileSize, this, 10, 70, "photo.jpg", "image/jpeg");*/
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG + " - doInBackground(String... arg0)", "httpRequest.postSocket() has NOT been called.");

            return -1;
        }

        return 1;
    }

  }

  //
  public class HttpRequest {

     private final String boundary = "-----------------------******";
     private final String newLine = "\r\n";
     private final int maxBufferSize = 4096;

     private final String header = 
       "POST / HTTP/1.1\n" +
       "Host: %s\n" +
       "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.10) Gecko/20071115 Firefox/2.0.0.10\n" +
       "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5\n" +
       "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\n" +
       "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate\n" +
       "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\n" +
       "Keep-Alive: 300\n" +
       "Connection: keep-alive\n" +
       "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary + "\n" +
       "Content-Length: %s\n\n";

     public void postSocket(String sUrl, 
                            Map params, 
                            InputStream stream,
                            PutOrderFilesTask task, 
                            int startProgress, 
                            int endProgress, 
                            String fileName, 
                            String contentType) {

         OutputStream writer = null;
         BufferedReader reader = null;
         Socket socket = null;

         Log.e(TAG + " - postSocket()", "vars in post socket have been populated.");

         try {
            int bytesAvailable;
            int bufferSize;
            int bytesRead;
            //int totalProgress = endProgress - startProgress;

            //task.myPublishProgress(new Long(startProgress));

            String openingPart = writeContent(params, fileName, contentType);
            String closingPart = newLine + "--" + boundary + "--" + newLine;
            long totalLength = openingPart.length() + closingPart.length();

            // strip off the leading http:// otherwise the Socket will not work
            String socketUrl = sUrl;

            Log.e(TAG + " - postSocket()", "socketUrl is: " + socketUrl);

            if (socketUrl.startsWith("http://")) {
                socketUrl = socketUrl.substring("http://".length());
            }

            socket = new Socket(socketUrl, 80);

            Log.e(TAG + " - postSocket()", "Socket as a string: " + socket.getPort());
            Log.e(TAG + " - postSocket()", "Socket port number is: " + socket.getPort());
            Log.e(TAG + " - postSocket()", "Connection state of socket is: " + socket.isConnected());

            socket.setKeepAlive(true);

            writer = socket.getOutputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            writer.write(String.format(header, socketUrl, Long.toString(totalLength)).getBytes());
            writer.write(openingPart.getBytes());

            bytesAvailable = stream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);

            Log.e(TAG + " - postSocket()", "bufferSize is: " + bufferSize);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            bytesRead = stream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            int readSoFar = bytesRead;

            //task.myPublishProgress(new Long(startProgress + Math.round(totalProgress * readSoFar / streamLength)));

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = stream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = stream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                readSoFar += bytesRead;
                //task.myPublishProgress(new Long(startProgress + Math.round(totalProgress * readSoFar / streamLength)));
            }

            stream.close();
            writer.write(closingPart.getBytes());

            //Log.d(Cards.LOG_TAG, closingPart);

            writer.flush();

            // read the response
            String s = reader.readLine();
            // do something with response s 
         } catch (Exception e) {
            //throw new HttpRequestException(e);

             Log.e(TAG + " - postSocket()", "Catch bit of the try and catch in postSocket()"); 
         } finally {
            if (writer != null) { try { writer.close(); writer = null;} catch (Exception ignore) {}}
            if (reader != null) { try { reader.close(); reader = null;} catch (Exception ignore) {}}
            if (socket != null) { try {socket.close(); socket = null;} catch (Exception ignore) {}}
         }   
    }

     /**
      * Populate the multipart request parameters into one large stringbuffer which will later allow us to 
      * calculate the content-length header which is mandatotry when putting objects in an S3
      * bucket
      * 
      * @param params
      * @param fileName the name of the file to be uploaded
      * @param contentType the content type of the file to be uploaded
      * @return
      */

     private String writeContent(Map params, String fileName, String contentType) {

         StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

         Set keys = params.keySet();

         for (Object key : keys) {
             Object val = params.get(key);

             buf.append("--")
              .append(boundary)
              .append(newLine);

             buf.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"")
              .append(key)
              .append("\"")
              .append(newLine)
              .append(newLine)
              .append(val)
              .append(newLine);
         }

         buf.append("--")
          .append(boundary)
          .append(newLine);

         buf.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"")
          .append(fileName)
          .append("\"")
          .append(newLine);

         buf.append("Content-Type: ")
          .append(contentType)
          .append(newLine)
          .append(newLine);

         return buf.toString();
     }

  }
```

My problem is that I'm encountering issues when I need to all the postSocket method as indicated above.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Note: The method getManfcAndModelNumb() returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be willing to consider an alternative:

```
        class S3 extends AmazonS3Client
         {final String bucket;
          S3(String u, String p, String Bucket)
           {super(new BasicAWSCredentials(u, p));
            bucket = Bucket;
           }
          boolean put(String k, String v)      
           {try 
             {final ByteArrayInputStream b = new ByteArrayInputStream(v.toString().getBytes());
              putObject(bucket, k, b, new ObjectMetadata());
              setObjectAcl(bucket, k, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);  // Has to be here to allow change to reduced redundancy
              changeObjectStorageClass(bucket, k, StorageClass.ReducedRedundancy);
              setObjectAcl(bucket, k, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);  // Has to be repeated because it is now a new object again
              return true; 
             }
            catch(Exception e) {log("Cannot put "+bucket+"/"+k+" to S3 because "+e);}
            return false; 
           }
        }
```